# Is there any good reason to transpose a tensor from NHWC to NCHW?

Tags: tensorflow

I often see the transpose implementation in tensorflow code. I wonder why one would want to transpose the NHWC tensor to NCHW. Please give me the good example and the reason behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than citing the documentation. You should read into how CUDA works and think about how to implement most operations.

The reason for NCHW generally being faster than NHWC is how the CUDA kernels are written. In CUDA you need to specify what each thread is doing like

```
const int threads = 32;
dim3 block(threads, threads);
dim3 grid(up2(W / 2, threads), up2(H, threads), B);

kernel<Dtype> <<< grid, block>>> (args ...)
```

Here you get 3 indices `threadId.z, threadId.y, threadId.x`. And these threads are organized in warps (hardware design).

And you want to have *coalesced memory transaction*, which means the threads are ordered in such a way, that the GPU can nicely operate in a fast way.

To sum it up:
You want to have "threadId.x" being the most inner-loop and you should organize the data layout such that it reading them in coalesced way. The ideal data structure should accessible by

```
b * C * H * W + c * H * W + h * W + w
```

where lower letters denote the index and capitalized letters denotes the shape (e.g., 0 <= w < W).

In convolution operations (a part of the most used layer) what you are essentially doing is cropping a region in each channel computing a dot production with a region in another channel (from another tensor). So the indices which need to run crazy fast are the height-idx and width-idx. In the end, you are adding along the channel axis (like the convolution formulae suggest). This also explains, why it makes no difference to consider NWHC, NCWH.

This has an impact on how you order the data. And it is the reason you want to have the memory layout I described above.

The worst layout would be:

```
H, C, B, in threadId.z, threadId.y, threadId.x
```

The best layout would be:

```
B, C, H in threadId.z, threadId.y, threadId.x
```

The same is (mostly) true for GEMM as well (here one matrix should be transpose). There is no source for CuDNN available. But you might be interested in looking into [cutlass](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass).

Comment: Note, however, that the question was not "Why is NCHW faster than NHWC", but simply why are there data format changes in programs using Tensorflow. While your answer is a great reply to "why" things are faster, citing TF's documentation is IMO more than enough to solve the OP's question.

Comment: I feel an answer should really help to understand the *reason* for "why one would want to transpose the NHWC tensor to NCHW". Copying the text from the documentation which can be found within 1 minute using google I do not count as an answer. And it is just a justification not an explanation.
But I might be wrong as your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

From the [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#data_formats) of Tensorflow:

> NHWC is the TensorFlow default and NCHW is the optimal format to use
>   when training on NVIDIA GPUs using cuDNN. [...] The brief history of these two formats is that TensorFlow started by using NHWC because it was a little faster on CPUs. In the long term, we are working on tools to auto rewrite graphs to make switching between the formats transparent and take advantages of micro optimizations where a GPU Op may be faster using NHWC than the normally most efficient NCHW.

Essentially, cuDNN is optimized for NCHW, while CPU-only tensorflow is optimized for NHWC. Switching from one to the other is just a matter of performance maximization and/or unavailability of certain operations in a specific data format.